# ARM supported emulator with Android 13+

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-13

I have an android app that works on only arm supported device.
To emulate my android app, I used to use LDPlayer. It supports android 9. Currently I need to make my app work on android 13+. Which emulator can I use? I tried an android emulator with ABI images, but it does not support on my x86_64 cpu. I know all the other emulators don't support android 13. What should I do now?